# What is restoreLevelAfterRunningModal and why is it being sent to my destroyed NSWindow?

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access, nszombie

I have a modal window, which was causing problems when destroyed. I learned how to use Zombies and I got this error message:`-[NSWindow _restoreLevelAfterRunningModal]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6000001f9500` The address listed is the address of the NSWindow I used for the modal dialog, which I let fall out of scope because it's never used again. The most perplexing thing is that I can't find restoreLevelAfterRunningModal anywhere in Apple's documentation. I'm using ARC by the way.

Comment: The method is private, indicated by the underscore.,when does the crash happen exactly? Can you let the window live a bit longer?

Comment: I figured it out- the Zombie was created because the modal window was released on close, but there was still a ref to in in my NSDocument subclass (I think)